# in TFS GetChangesForChangeset returns the other file in the item instead of the queried file

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk, tfs-analysis

I am calling this method to bring me changes for the specific file ("test.resx.cs" ) 
however, it brings to me the other file in the workitem ("test.resx" ).

But if I set `ItemSpec` to `null`, then all the changed files will be returned including "test.resx.cs". but that is not good because I have to bring all the files items in that changeset, which make it slow.

```
 _versionControlServer.GetChangesForChangeset(changeSet.ChangesetId, false, 200, new ItemSpec("test.resx.cs", RecursionType.Full), new string[]{ "ItemId", "ServerItem", "DownloadUrl" },true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the `ItemSpec` is not used for retrieve the changes for a specific file, once you enter a file item it will parse the path of the item. Pleas see [ItemSpec Constructor (String, RecursionType)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/bb132169%28v%3Dvs.120%29) for details.

> Parameters
>
> item
>
> Type: System.String
>
> **The path of the item to include in this item specifier.**

So, generally you will not get the only file item you specified, unless it's the only change item within the path...

So, we have to get all the files items in that changeset , then filter out the specific item...  (Even use the REST API, it will also get all changes first...Please see [Changesets - Get Changeset Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/tfvc/changesets/get%20changeset%20changes?view=vsts-rest-4.1) for details.)

Comment: Thanks, but for me I use VS2015 , so I cant use that API call.is there a way with _versionControlServer.GetChangesForChangeset to get only one item instead of all items in changeset?

Comment: @sino No any way, you have to get all changes item first, then filter the needed ones...